# Performance related issue regarding times like 00:00:00:000

Tags: c#

I have [this ListView](http://spunit.tk/x/Untitled-1.png). My goal is to add / subtract a fixed time to all the times / selected times in the list. The thing is that there will be somewhat around 1000-3000 rows in it, so it takes some time. My goal is to make this as fast for the computer as possible.

Right now if I spam-run the function, it takes some time for the form to finish, and if I chose to do it with selected rows, half of them, then the form freezes for a while before finishing.

My code right now looks like this ([here's a picture of the code for better view](http://spunit.tk/x/564654.png)):

```
    public void PlusMinus(bool plus)
    {
        int items_to_set = 0;
        int msec_start = 0;
        int msec_end = 0;
        int msec_box = Convert.ToInt32(mskTime.Text.Substring(9, 3)) +
        (Convert.ToInt32(mskTime.Text.Substring(6, 2)) * 1000) +
        (Convert.ToInt32(mskTime.Text.Substring(3, 2)) * 60000) +
        (Convert.ToInt32(mskTime.Text.Substring(0, 2)) * 3600000);
        if (rbtnAll.Checked) { items_to_set = listSub.Items.Count; }
        else { items_to_set = listSub.SelectedItems.Count; }


        if (rbtnAll.Checked)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < items_to_set; i++)
            {
                msec_start = Convert.ToInt32(listSub.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text.Substring(9, 3)) +
                (Convert.ToInt32(listSub.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text.Substring(6, 2)) * 1000) +
                (Convert.ToInt32(listSub.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text.Substring(3, 2)) * 60000) +
                (Convert.ToInt32(listSub.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text.Substring(0, 2)) * 3600000);
                msec_end = Convert.ToInt32(listSub.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text.Substring(9, 3)) +
                (Convert.ToInt32(listSub.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text.Substring(6, 2)) * 1000) +
                (Convert.ToInt32(listSub.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text.Substring(3, 2)) * 60000) +
                (Convert.ToInt32(listSub.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text.Substring(0, 2)) * 3600000);

                if (plus == true) { msec_start += msec_box; msec_end += msec_box; }
                else { msec_start -= msec_box; msec_end -= msec_box; }
                TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(msec_start);
                listSub.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}:{3:D3}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds);
                ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(msec_end);
                listSub.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}:{3:D3}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < items_to_set; i++)
            {
                msec_start = Convert.ToInt32(listSub.Items[listSub.SelectedIndices[i]].SubItems[1].Text.Substring(9, 3)) +
                (Convert.ToInt32(listSub.Items[listSub.SelectedIndices[i]].SubItems[1].Text.Substring(6, 2)) * 1000) +
                (Convert.ToInt32(listSub.Items[listSub.SelectedIndices[i]].SubItems[1].Text.Substring(3, 2)) * 60000) +
                (Convert.ToInt32(listSub.Items[listSub.SelectedIndices[i]].SubItems[1].Text.Substring(0, 2)) * 3600000);
                msec_end = Convert.ToInt32(listSub.Items[listSub.SelectedIndices[i]].SubItems[2].Text.Substring(9, 3)) +
                (Convert.ToInt32(listSub.Items[listSub.SelectedIndices[i]].SubItems[2].Text.Substring(6, 2)) * 1000) +
                (Convert.ToInt32(listSub.Items[listSub.SelectedIndices[i]].SubItems[2].Text.Substring(3, 2)) * 60000) +
                (Convert.ToInt32(listSub.Items[listSub.SelectedIndices[i]].SubItems[2].Text.Substring(0, 2)) * 3600000);

                if (plus == true) { msec_start += msec_box; msec_end += msec_box; }
                else { msec_start -= msec_box; msec_end -= msec_box; }
                TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(msec_start);
                listSub.Items[listSub.SelectedIndices[i]].SubItems[1].Text = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}:{3:D3}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds);
                ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(msec_end);
                listSub.Items[listSub.SelectedIndices[i]].SubItems[2].Text = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}:{3:D3}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds);
            }
        }
    }
```

So is there some changes I could make that would be a somewhat big positive impact on the performance here?

Comment: This sounds like a candidate for `CodeReview`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't parse the strings at all. Instead, store the data as `TimeSpan`s so there is no parsing at all.

Storing data as strings is bad-practice anyway because it clutters up your code with serialization and deserialization.

Where you store the data is not that important. You can use the `object Tag` property that is on most WinForms objects or store it elsewhere (maybe in a custom list or dictionary).

Also, your code looks highly redundant. Put common subexpressions into local variables. This will improve code quality and performance.

Comment: It's because I'm so used to strings that I normally use that, I'm kindo of a beginner at C#. A bad habit. Maybe you could give an axample how this is done? Like how would you write what's inside rbtnAll.Checked? Thanks.

Comment: Well, I certainly won't translate everything but the basic usage is like this: `listviewsubitem.tag = myTimeSpan;` and `((TimeSpan)(listviewsubitem.tag))` to store and retrieve a TimeSpan value. Try it.